# How to make a valid backup for Evolution and restore it

Tags: bash, shell-script, backup, email, evolution

Im working with the evolution mail client, and I have been migrating some machines. So in order to do so, the next script is runned:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p ~/path_to_backupdir/mail-backup
mkdir -p ~/path_to_backupdir/mail-backup/config
mkdir -p ~/path_to_backupdir/mail-backup/local

cp -r ~/.config/evolution/ ~/path_to_backupdir/mail-backup/config/
cp -r ~/.local/share/evolution/ ~/path_to_backupdir/mail-backup/local/
tar -czvf mail-backup.tar.gz ~/path_to_backupdir/mail-backup/
```

That provides a `mail-backup.tar.gz` file, and either using the builtin method in the gui of File>Restaurate Evolution Data
or the backup script

```
#!/bin/bash

tar xvf mail-backup.tar.gz
cd mail-backup/
cd config
mv evolution/ ~/.config/
cd ..
cd local
mv evolution/ ~/.local/share/
```

Evolution does nothing, or simply says "back_up_file" is not valid, checked the permissions on the back up files and directories and are the same; when looking at the terminal it says something about a mismatch but I don't know how to interpret it:

```
**evolution-backup-Message: 20:23:35.948: First result 0
evolution-backup-Message: 20:24:09.583: Second result 256
module-backup-restore-Message: 20:24:09.590: Sanity check result 1:1 256
**
```